# UISplitViewController toggleMasterVisible method. Where is the method defined?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I can call properly "toggleMasterVisible" method as a Button action but I want to expand the method like this.

```
(In Button action. It works)
.h 
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
@end

.m
UIBarButtonItem *listBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"] 
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
target:self.splitViewController 
action:@selector(toggleMasterVisible:)];


(I want to expand the method)
.m
UIBarButtonItem *listBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"] 
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
target:self 
action:@selector(toggleMasterVisibleIfCondtionIsOK:)];

-(void)toggleMasterVisibleIfCondtionIsOK
{
     if(isConditionOK){
          [self.splitViewController toggleMasterVisible];
     }
}
```

However, I got an error which is "No visible @interface for 'UISplitViewController' declares". Where is the method defined? I could not find the method on the reference(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) and how can I call the method? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I got it to work with:

```
[self.splitViewController performSelector:@selector(toggleMasterVisible:)];
```

Comment: This is the first response to this problem that is reasonable and actually works. Thank you very much.

Comment: I also had it working when i was with the previous Xcode, but now i updated to ios 7 and it is always saying that the method is unrecognized: masterButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self.splitViewController action:@selector(toggleMasterVisible:)]; can you help me?

Comment: It's a private API, the Xcode validation is flagging it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Just define it in an [anonymous category](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/objective-c-anonymous-categories/) as follows:

```
@interface UISplitViewController()
- (void)toggleMasterVisible:(id)sender;
@end
```